# Equal Arrays AngularJS Pro

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I need to show object only if one of it's properties equals to array.

I have a controller in app.js:

```
app.controller('checkBoxController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.ingredients= [
        {label: 'Egg', value: 1},
        {label: 'Milk', value: 2},
    $scope.selection=[];
    $scope.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection(ingredientLabel) {
        var idx = $scope.selection.indexOf(ingredientLabel);
        if (idx > -1) {
            $scope.selection.splice(idx, 1);
        }
        else {
            $scope.selection.push(ingredientLabel);
        }
    };
});
```

and an html code for it:

```
<span style="color:black;" class="selected-item">Selected Items:<span>
<div ng-repeat="label in selection" class="selected-item">
</div>
<div class="list-group">
    <div class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="product in meals.products" ng-show="product.contents==selection">
        <h1>{{product.name}}</h1>
        <meal-gallery></meal-gallery>
        <meal-tabs></meal-tabs>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I Have `{ name: 'Scrambled Egg', contents: "Egg"}` in array of products. So I need to show product if it's contents equals to selected ingredients. 
I do not have problems when it is only one ingredient like "Egg", but if I need contents of two equal to selected?

Comment: angularjs pro? is that some kind of module? It looks like you implemented a typo into your code when posting here, your array isn't complete.

Comment: Unless the two objects are literally the same object, you can't use indexOf in that way. `var x = {}; var y = x; x == y; // true` `var x = {'name': 'pie'}; x == {'name': 'pie'}; // false`

Answer (score 1):

It would be best to use a custom filter.

If you add [lodash](https://lodash.com/) to your application, you can create a filter that will preform a following operation:

```
angular.module('common', [])
.filter('canBeMadeFrom', function() {
  return function(product, ingredients) {
    return _.intersection(product.contents, ingredients).length == product.contents.length';
  };
});
```

this will return true if all of products contents are contained in ingredients

use it like this

```
ng-repeat='product in products | canBeMadeFrom:ingredients'
```

Comment: But I need to return true only if exact items are in the product.contents and false if at least one of them is not

Comment: I've edited my answer to check if all product contents are in ingredients array

Answer (score 0):

Use a filter.

```
<div ng-repeat=product in products |filter: product.a === a && product.b === b>
```

You can also use a function for filter. It's a function that takes in an item and returns Boolean

Comment: Can't I just use an array for contents of product? Like this: { name: 'Scrambled Egg', contents: ["Egg", "Milk"]}

Comment: But I have a problem. Somehow I have my code working only when product.contents==selection and "Egg"(from product.content) == ["Egg"]. That is strange. I can not understand what is the problem